# Is it always advisable for passengers to wear seat belts when a 747 is on final approach?

Tags: safety, military, approach

I noticed in [this recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdWWr4O2P04) that some of the passengers are not wearing their seat belts. I realize this is not a typical commercial flight, but is it advisable to wear seat belts when a 747 or similar aircraft is flying so close to the ground, (apparently) during a final approach? Or are the safety precautions here so thorough that it's not actually necessary in this case?

[image: nice view! (crop 2)]

[image: nice view! (crop 1)]

[image: nice view!]

Comment: Related [14 CFR 91.107](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.107) but its important to note that the airplane in the pictures is Air Force One.

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks! I'm guessing then that this is not necessarily considered a "*U.S.-registered civil aircraft,*" although if it were, the phrases like "*...or gondola or an airship type certificated before November 2, 1987*" or "*Unless otherwise authorized by the Administrator—*" might also come in to play. But in this question I'm really asking about *safety* and *advisability*, not regulations.

Comment: AFO is owned and operated by US Air Force and is subject to different regulations. Its always advisable to wear a seatbelt on an aircraft as an accident or malfunction can occur at any time.

Comment: For every person who advises to do something, you'll find another who advises not to. As a pilot though I would recommend wearing it as much as possible, there is always unexpected turbulence or other things that can injure you or the people around you.

Comment: You've asked a question the answer to which is a matter of opinion. My opinion is that when you're in a seat, whether a pilot seat or a passenger seat, it's best to have the seat belt fastened, though you may have the belt adjusted so it's comfortably loose. However, in reasonable flight conditions I have no problem with unfastening it to move about the cockpit or cabin. When sleeping across seats, I usually did not use a belt. In 3-man cockpits of 727s and 747s, I used to sit crossways in the captain's seat for extended periods while talking with the f.o. and f.e. without wearing a seat belt.

Comment: @Terry So was that captain's prerogative or is that one off the things you can fess up to now being retired? :)

Comment: My personal rule is always to wear my seat belt unless I want to get up. Having said that, I once landed standing up, holding on the back of a C-130 pilot's seat. If everything is going right, seat belts are pretty unnecessary. It's just when things are going wrong that you wish you were strapped in.

Comment: Consider that this may be an "all eyes" situation.  Since this is a new landing zone, could it be that "all eyes" have been requested to scan for threats?  I know this is a stretch, given the level of security involved for POTUS, but I know it is done in other military applications.

Comment: I was going to say something funny @Keeta, but actually, considering this particular situation overall, maybe!

Comment: Actually @HowardMiller it's about 10 seconds *before* something goes wrong that I would wish that *all of the other passengers around me* were snapped in too!

Comment: @Keeta 'this may be an "all eyes" situation". Very unlikely that it's important enough for the President to be watching for danger, but not the photographer taking the picture. Almost certainly a case where the publicity value of getting a picture of the President arriving in Havana outweighs the tiny risk of him not wearing a seatbelt.

Comment: @TomMcW There was nothing in our ops specs or for that matter in FAA rules back then (1990s), at least as I remember, that required seat belts or shoulder harnesses during cruise flight. I get the impression, but do not know, that today's cockpits are much less relaxed than we were back then.

Comment: @HowardMiller I made trips standing up in 727s from Terre Haute through Minneapolis to Seattle and vice-versa in the late 1980s. It was a night freight operation with all the pilots based in Terre Haute, but a lot of us lived in Oregon and Washington. Two jump seats filled, one sitting on the toilet, two standing was normal.

Comment: @Terry Standing up!? Like a flying jitney! My company would've had none of that in the 90's. They made us shave our beards to jumpseat because of the 02 masks. But I did get to do what you were saying and fold up the armrests and sleep across the whole row. The 47's were nice to jetmpseat in. Too bad we only had two of them.

Comment: @TomMcW I doubt the company ever knew what we were doing. Insofar as sleeping on a 747, we used to ferry 747s empty except for half a dozen cockpit crews, a purser, and a few maintenance people to and from Jakarta for the Hajj. What those not operating would do was to put up all the arm rests for a middle row (5 seats), then take the seat cushions from the row in front and the row in back to further pad your sleeping row. Made for a very comfortable bed.

Comment: @Terry Was there, at that time, no 91.105 requirement that crewmembers "keep the safety belt fastened while at the crewmember station"?

Comment: @JonathanWalters Your comment made me curious, and I found http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library%5CrgFAR.nsf/0/910628D28B527432852566CF00613CBE?OpenDocument which seems to indicate that reg was first published in Oct 1992. My 727 and 747 flying started in 1988 and extended through 1992. Thus it would appear I started my jet experience without that regulation. Frankly, I don't remember it being publicized, but it's been a long time since now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is, of course, advisable to wear your seat belt, yes. However, there appears to be somewhat of a tradition of not always wearing seat belts on Air Force One:

Stanley B. Greenberg, *Dispatches from the War Room: In the Trenches with Five Extraordinary Leaders* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=rGTwXgpDUXUC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=air%20force%20one%20seat%20belts&source=bl&ots=COpztRELQP&sig=yPUJNu9msgO1ABaFN1FP50IXJ0w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirsOnS3uHLAhUS9WMKHRjaBCg4ChDoAQhUMAk#v=onepage&q=air%20force%20one%20seat%20belts&f=false)):

> Nobody wears seat belts and everyone uses their cell phones while the
>   plane is taking off.

Presumably the crew would provide a special warning if they expected a rough ride.

Comment: There are multiple good answers here, but you've also taken the time to find additional supporting data. So in addition to the peanuts, M&Ms, pens, etc. there are other perks that come with this job - you get to not wear your seat belt sometimes. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is always advisable for passengers to wear the provided safety belts in all phases of flight. This is especially true for aircraft on takeoff, landing, in low level flight, or in any other flight regimes that are especially prone to turbulence or other risk exposure.

A large, heavy aircraft—such as a [B747](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747)—will be less affected by wake or mechanical turbulence than would a smaller aircraft—such as a [CRJ200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_CRJ200#CRJ200) or a [C172](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_172). However, even large, heavy aircraft can be subjected to severe turbulence that could result in injury or death if passengers are not restrained by appropriate safety belts.

Additionally, for flights conducted under [14 CFR 121](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=20524ff5a58bd9263808557ecf34715e&mc=true&node=pt14.3.121&rgn=div5#se14.3.121_1311)—which I am confident is a majority of the US operated passenger flights involving the B747 (though not, obviously, Air Force One pictured in the question above)—passengers are generally required to:

> occupy an approved seat or berth with a separate safety belt properly secured about him or her during movement on the surface, **takeoff**, and **landing**
>   *<sub>Excerpted from 14 CFR 121.311 (b)</sub>*

Comment: It might also be worth noting that, at least in the U.S., the same requirement applies to GA, per [14 CFR 91.107](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.107). So, even if it's a privately-owned 747, the seat belt requirement is still in place during taxi, takeoff, and landing.

Comment: Yes, this is also noted in the comments under the question.

Comment: This is *also* a correct answer - and is up-voted more because the message is important. Always keep your belt fastened - even when the light is out - even if you think you are in control of the situation. Stuff happens.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about what Obama does in particular . It's always advised to wear seat belt whether you are in Boeing 747 or other small planes.

According to this [Telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/news/Will-wearing-a-seatbelt-on-a-plane-save-your-life/) article:

> "Seat belts are required and designed to ensure passenger safety and reduce the risk of injury, particularly during deceleration, turbulence and unplanned or difficult to predict events.”

And later on in the same article:

> Last year, severe turbulence caused three EasyJet crew members to “hit
>   the ceiling” over Italy, according to a passenger eye-witness, with
>   one sustaining a hip injury.

Now all that can be said is if you don't want to be next victim wear the seatbelts.

Comment: Wow thanks now it sounds & looks better.